# Style object to string

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to convert my generated style object to a style-string. 
Basically what jQuery does by applying `$(elem).css(styleObject)`, but without a target element.

Is there anyway to transform an object like

```
bodyStyle = {
   lineHeight: 10,
   backgroundColor: '#444',
   height: 50
}
```

to a string like

```
line-height: 10px; background-color: #444; height:50px;
```

What I'm doing now doesn't seem to be the most elegant solution:

```
if(styleObj) {
    var style = $('<div>').css(styleObj).attr('style');
    return style;
}
```

Comment: If that's the result you are wanting there wouldn't be any simpler way

Comment: I don't see anything particularly ugly in your code. Yes, you could browse jQuery source code and replicate the internal functions involved but... what'd be the point if you're already using jQuery?

Comment: Perfect, it just felt like it wasn't the most optimal solution.